# Is there any search query to search in database for the value which was replaced by another value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have created a table in sql database with some columns.In that, one column is P_active with char(1), and default value as 'Y'.While displaying in gridview, status column is showing 'Y', but i want to show 'Active' instead of 'Y'.I have done this, but the problem is while searching,in textbox if i enter 'Active' or any letter a/c/t/i/v/e and click on search, the records with Active status should be shown but unfortunately, i am getting no records found if i enter any letter except 'Y'.So how to achieve this?

```
CS CODE:

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
        if (drv["P_active"].ToString() == "Y")
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Active";           
       }
}

protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlsearch.SelectedItem.Text == "Product Name")
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = bll.Search("P_name", txtsearch.Text);
    }                   
    else if (ddlsearch.SelectedItem.Text == "Status")
    {            
            GridView1.DataSource = bll.Search("P_active", txtsearch.Text);                                   
    }
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
}

BAL:
 public DataTable Search(string option, string val)
    {
        return dll.search(option, val);
    }

DAL:
 public DataTable search(string searchBy, string searchVal)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spsearchp", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchBy", searchBy);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchVal", searchVal);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[spsearchp]
@SearchBy   varchar(50),
@SearchVal  varchar(50)
AS 
BEGIN
IF @SearchBy = 'P_name'
BEGIN
select * from Products LEFT JOIN Category ON Products.PCid= Category.cid where P_name like '%' + @SearchVal + '%'
END
ELSE IF @SearchBy = 'P_active'
BEGIN
select * from Products LEFT JOIN Category ON Products.PCid= Category.cid WHERE P_active like '%' + @SearchVal + '%'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
select * from Products LEFT JOIN Category ON Products.PCid= Category.cid
END
END
```

Comment: So for display purposes you change the database content to something different. It seems pretty simple to reverse this logic when you need to search your db. If you get the word "Active" search for "Y"

Comment: I need to search with 'active' or any letter from active i.e a/c/t/i/v/e but not with 'Y'. How can i get this by Changing query?

Comment: Using "Active and Inactive" as keywords can work but you can't search for a and expect to get y. That will be a whole lot regex to do.

Comment: Change your BAL code. If option = "P_active" then val = "Y"

Comment: Hi steve , I am bit confused, can u pls modify my code